# How to give proper path to public/pdf.worker.js in the file located in src folder

Tags: reactjs, react-pdf

How to give proper path to public/pdf.worker.js in the file located in src folder.

I am working react-pdf, I have created pdf.worker.js inside public folder, I need to give path to it in one of the component inside src folder. like below

```
<Document
        file={pdf}
        options={{ workerSrc: "/pdf.worker.js" }}
        onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess}
      ></Document>
```

But the thing is I have configured jsconfig.json as below

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  }
}
```

I am thinking the path to pdf.worker.js is not right and it is not locating the file/loading the file

I have tried inside the component where I am using Document which is working fine

```
import { Document, Page, pdfjs } from "react-pdf";

pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/${pdfjs.version}/pdf.worker.js`;
```

but i need to load public/pdf.worker.js instead of doing it inside the component

Answer (score 1):

add in the index.html to make the file known

```
<head>
 <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/pdf.worker.js"></script>
```

make a script that copys the pdf.worker.js to your public folder

```
import path from 'node:path';
import fs from 'node:fs';

const pdfjsDistPath = path.dirname(import.meta.resolve('pdfjs-dist/package.json'));
const pdfWorkerPath = path.join(pdfjsDistPath, 'build', 'pdf.worker.js');

fs.copyFileSync(pdfWorkerPath.substring(5), 'public/pdf.worker.js');
```

execute in package.json

```
"build": "node copy_pdf_worker.mjs && react-scripts build",
```

Needs Node 20.
then you neither need pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = ... nor options={{ workerSrc: "/pdf.worker.js" }}. also nothing in the jsconfig.json